# keypress not working in browser android

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I already tried google the answer to my problem and I did not find. I need to capture the value with each key pressed;

Keypress works in desktop browser. But in android browser does not work. I researched and discovered that there is a bug in the android browser.

Anyone know how I can capture the value of the key typed by the user?

My current code:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[mask-number]',
  host: {
    '(keydown)': 'keypress($event)',
    '(blur)': 'focusout()'
  }
})

....

keypress($event){

   alert($event.key);
}

....
```

return in browser android:

```
unidefinid
```

Comment: Hook in to the `input` event instead of (or in addition to) the existing events.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to listen on keyup or keydown event.